# Default selected cell in collection view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to set a default selected cell in my collection view. When the collection view controller appears it should present the cell's content in a container. I tried :

```
myCollectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left)
```

in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear but it is still not selecting the first cell when the collection view is visible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you set up your collection view?  It's possible you're trying to select the cell before the collection view has loaded

Comment: I have set it up in one of my viewcontrollers above everything else

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it. In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I had to state:

```
if (cell.selected == false){
  let detailedViewController: ViewController = ....

  self.addChildViewController(detailedViewController)

  containerView.addSubview(detailedViewController.view)

 }
```

Comment: This solution worked but now the problem is that after deselecting a cell it returns back to the first cell. Any ideas how can I make a workaround and select the last selected cell when cell.select = false